# Laravel return page after deleted one row

Tags: php, laravel

how can I return to the same page after deleting something?

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\View;

class TableditControllerRolete extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $data = DB::table('Rolete')->get();
        return view('table_edit', compact('data'));
    }
    
    public function destroy($id){
        DB::delete('delete from Rolete where ProdusID = ?' ,[$id]);

    }
    

}
```

Web.php:

```
/*tabledit*/
Route::get('tabledit', 'TableditControllerRolete@index');
Route::get('delete/{id}','TableditControllerRolete@destroy');
```

And .blade:

```
<tbody>
                @foreach($data as $row)
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      <a href="$" class="btn btn-info" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> 
                       <a href = 'delete/{{$row->ProdusID}}' class="btn btn-danger" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                  </td>
               
                </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
```

So , she deleted from my table, but dosen't return to the same page.

Thanks

Comment: add `return Redirect::back();` in your controller after delete query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For returning to current page you should use laravel back() method using object chain. Follow the below code and  modify it accordingly.

```
class TableditControllerRolete extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $data = DB::table('Rolete')->get();
        return view('table_edit', compact('data'));
    }
    
    public function destroy($id){
        DB::delete('delete from Rolete where ProdusID = ?' ,[$id]);
       session()->flash('success','delete successful');
       return redirect()->back();


    }
    

}
```

In your view add this code anywhere

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
<p>{{ session()->get('success') }}
@endif
```

Comment: I can return something message after? Something alert bootstrap or modal?

Comment: yes you can send value as session with redirect()->back()->with('session_key','session_value');

Comment: i'm not sure how =)) , you can give me one example?

Comment: you are trying to previous page and show something after deleting (messages/text) ?

Comment: After redirect to give me one alert bootstrap with "Is done" or something that

Answer (score 0):

You can return something else, eg. a view:

```
   public function destroy($id){
    
    DB::delete('delete from Rolete where ProdusID = ?' ,[$id]);
    return View::make('path')->with('var',$var);

   }
```

the `with()` is optional. you can use `with()` if you want to pass some data to the view like `record deleted Successful` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect method, as you have not mentioned the laravel version here some way using laravel 8.x. you can find more on [official document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects)

```
public function destroy($id){
       DB::delete('delete from Rolete where ProdusID = ?' ,[$id]);
       return redirect('/yourpath'); 
       // return back(); return to previous page.
       // return redirect()->route('route name goes here');
       // return redirect()->action([HomeController::class, 'index']);
}
```